# encoding='utf-8' raise UnicodeEncodeError when opening utf-8 file with Chinese char

Tags: python, encoding, utf-8, python-3.x

I cann't open file with any Chinese charecter, with encording set to `utf-8`:

```
text = open('file.txt', mode='r', encoding='utf-8').read()
print(text)
```

`UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u70e6' in position 0: character maps to <undefined>`

The file is 100% utf-8.
http://asdfasd.net/423/file.txt
http://asdfasd.net/423/test.py
If I remove `encoding='utf-8'` everything is ok.

What is wrong here with encoding?
I always use `encoding='utf-8'` when opening files, I don't now what happened now.

Comment: You are not having a problem with reading the file, but with *writing* (or printing). Reading would lead to a `UnicodeDecodeError` instead, but you have a *encoding* problem.

Comment: See http://wiki.python.org/moin/PrintFails

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exception you see comes from **printing** your data. Printing requires that you encode the data to the encoding used by your terminal or Windows console.

You can see this from the exception (and from the traceback, but you didn't include that); if you have a problem with decoding data (which is what happens when you read from a file) then you would get a `UnicodeDecodeError`, you got a `UnicodeEncodeError` instead.

You need to either adjust your terminal or console encoding, or not print the data

See http://wiki.python.org/moin/PrintFails for troubleshooting help.